# MATLAB crashes while executing halftone mex wrapper function?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, image-processing, mex

Below screen shot is the result of the execution of the function in MATLAB.

```
a=imread('C:\CVIPtools\images\car.bmp');
ad=im2double(a);
ht = halftoneCVIP(ad,4,255, 0.5, 0, 0);
```

[image]

Halftoning: it's a methods for reducing the number of gray levels by creating dot patterns or dither patterns to represent various gray levels, reduces effective  spatial resolution also.

There are 6 methods in halftoning.
1. Floyd Stienberg
2. Dither
3. Threshold
4. Cluster 3
5. Cluster 4
6. Cluster 8

***Image *CVIPhalftone(Image  *cvip_Image,  int  halftone,  int
     maxval,   float   fthreshval,   CVIP_BOOLEAN   retain_image,
     CVIP_BOOLEAN verbose)***

```
  <cvip_Image> - pointer to input image
  <halftone> - indicates method used to convert  from  grays-
 cale  to  binary.  (one  of  QT_FS,  QT_THRESH,  QT_DITHER8,
 QT_CLUSTER3, QT_CLUSTER4, QT_CLUSTER8)
  <maxval> - specifies maximum range of input image  (usually
 255)
  <fthreshval> - threshold value (for QT_THRESH) between [0.0
 ... 1.0].
  <retain_image> - retain image after  writing  (CVIP_YES  or
 CVIP_NO)?
  <verbose> - shall I be verbose (CVIP_YES or CVIP_NO)?**
```

I am trying to reuse a halftone function origianlly written in C. My objective is to make this function executable in MATLAB by writing a wrapper function using MEX.

Below are the code I have written and I am able to compile successfully without any errors. However, while executing the function MATLAB crashes. Does anyone know the reason behind this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mex.h"
#include "CVIPtools.h"
#include "CVIPimage.h"
#include "CVIPdef.h"
#include "CVIPmap.h"
#include "limits.h"
#include "threshold.h"
#include <float.h>
#include "CVIPmatrix.h"

#include "dithers.h"
#include "CVIPhalftone.h"

#define CVIP_WHITE 1
#define CVIP_BLACK 0

#define FS_SCALE 1024
#define HALF_FS_SCALE 512


Image *CVIPhalftone(Image *cvip_Image, int halftone, int maxval, float fthreshval, CVIP_BOOLEAN retain_image, CVIP_BOOLEAN verbose)
{
    byte* grayrow;
    register byte* gP;
    byte* bitrow;
    register byte* bP;
    int rows, cols, row;
    int col, limitcol, format;
    char function_name[] = {"CVIPhalftone"};
    long threshval, sum;
    long* thiserr;
    long* nexterr;
    long* temperr;
    int fs_direction;
    Image *bit_Image;

    cols = cvip_Image->image_ptr[0]->cols;
    rows = cvip_Image->image_ptr[0]->rows;

    bit_Image = (Image *) image_allocate(cvip_Image->image_format, BINARY, 1, rows, cols, CVIP_BYTE, REAL);

    format = cvip_Image->image_format;
    if( !(format==PBM || format==PGM || format==TIF || format==RAS || format==BIN || format==ITX) ) {
       if(verbose)
          fprintf(stderr, "\n%s: casting image to format that supports binary images - (PBM).\n",function_name);
       bit_Image->image_format = PBM;
    }
    mexPrintf("Till here 1\n");
    /* Initialize. */
    switch ( halftone )
    {
    case QT_FS:         // QT_FS=1 defined in CVIPhalftone.h

    if(verbose)
       fprintf(stderr, "%s: performing boustrophedonic Floyd-Steinberg error diffusion.\n\n",function_name);
    /* Initialize Floyd-Steinberg error vectors. */
    thiserr = (long*) calloc( cols + 2, sizeof(long) );
    nexterr = (long*) calloc( cols + 2, sizeof(long) );
    srand( (int) ( time( 0 ) ^ getpid( ) ) );
    for ( col = 0; col < cols + 2; ++col )
        thiserr[col] = ( rand( ) % FS_SCALE - HALF_FS_SCALE ) / 4;
        /* (random errors in [-FS_SCALE/8 .. FS_SCALE/8]) */
    fs_direction = 1;
    threshval = fthreshval * FS_SCALE;
    break;

    case QT_THRESH:         // QT_THRESH=2 defined in CVIPhalftone.h

    threshval = fthreshval * maxval + 0.999999;
    if(verbose) {
       fprintf(stderr, "%s: performing simple thresholding operation.\n",function_name);
       fprintf(stderr, "%s: threshold level - %ld.\n\n",function_name, threshval);
    }
    break;


    case QT_DITHER8:        // QT_DITHER8=3 defined in CVIPhalftone.h
    break;


    case QT_CLUSTER3:       // QT_CLUSTER3=4 defined in CVIPhalftone.h
    break;

    case QT_CLUSTER4:       // QT_CLUSTER4=5 defined in CVIPhalftone.h

    break;

    case QT_CLUSTER8:       // QT_CLUSTER8=6 defined in CVIPhalftone.h

    break;

    default:
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: can't happen... but apparently something did?!?\n" , function_name); break;
    }
    mexPrintf("Till here 2\n");
    for ( row = 0; row < rows; ++row )
    {
    grayrow = (byte *) ((byte **) cvip_Image->image_ptr[0]->rptr)[row];
    bitrow  = (byte *) ((byte **) bit_Image->image_ptr[0]->rptr)[row];

    switch ( halftone )
        {
        case QT_FS:

        for ( col = 0; col < cols + 2; ++col )
        nexterr[col] = 0;
        if ( fs_direction )
        {
        col = 0;
        limitcol = cols;
        gP = grayrow;
        bP = bitrow;
        }
        else
        {
        col = cols - 1;
        limitcol = -1;
        gP = &(grayrow[col]);
        bP = &(bitrow[col]);
        }
        do
        {
        sum = ( (long) *gP * FS_SCALE ) / maxval + thiserr[col + 1];
        if ( sum >= threshval )
            {
            *bP = CVIP_WHITE;
            sum = sum - threshval - HALF_FS_SCALE;
            }
        else
            *bP = CVIP_BLACK;

        if ( fs_direction )
            {
            thiserr[col + 2] += ( sum * 7 ) / 16;
            nexterr[col    ] += ( sum * 3 ) / 16;
            nexterr[col + 1] += ( sum * 5 ) / 16;
            nexterr[col + 2] += ( sum     ) / 16;

            ++col;
            ++gP;
            ++bP;
            }
        else
            {
            thiserr[col    ] += ( sum * 7 ) / 16;
            nexterr[col + 2] += ( sum * 3 ) / 16;
            nexterr[col + 1] += ( sum * 5 ) / 16;
            nexterr[col    ] += ( sum     ) / 16;

            --col;
            --gP;
            --bP;
            }
        }
        while ( col != limitcol );
        temperr = thiserr;
        thiserr = nexterr;
        nexterr = temperr;
        fs_direction = ! fs_direction;
        break;

        case QT_THRESH:

        for ( col = 0, gP = grayrow, bP = bitrow; col < cols; ++col, ++gP, ++bP )
        if ( *gP >= threshval )
            *bP = CVIP_WHITE;
        else
            *bP = CVIP_BLACK;
        break;

        case QT_DITHER8:

        for ( col = 0, gP = grayrow, bP = bitrow; col < cols; ++col, ++gP, ++bP )
        if ( *gP >= dither8[row % 16][col % 16] * ( maxval + 1 ) / 256 )
            *bP = CVIP_WHITE;
        else
            *bP = CVIP_BLACK;
        break;

        case QT_CLUSTER3:

        for ( col = 0, gP = grayrow, bP = bitrow; col < cols; ++col, ++gP, ++bP )
        if ( *gP >= cluster3[row %6][col %6 ] * ( maxval + 1 ) / 18 )
            *bP = CVIP_WHITE;
        else
            *bP = CVIP_BLACK;
        break;

        case QT_CLUSTER4:

        for ( col = 0, gP = grayrow, bP = bitrow; col < cols; ++col, ++gP, ++bP )
        if ( *gP >= cluster4[row %8][col%8] * ( maxval + 1 ) / 32 )
            *bP = CVIP_WHITE;
        else
            *bP = CVIP_BLACK;
        break;

        case QT_CLUSTER8:

        for ( col = 0, gP = grayrow, bP = bitrow; col < cols; ++col, ++gP, ++bP )
        if ( *gP >= cluster8[row %16][col %16] * ( maxval + 1 ) / 128 )
            *bP = CVIP_WHITE;
        else
            *bP = CVIP_BLACK;
        break;

        default:
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: can't happen... but apparently something did?!?\n" , function_name); break;
        }
    }
    mexPrintf("Till here 1\n");
if(!retain_image)
   image_free(cvip_Image);
return bit_Image;
mexPrintf("Till here 2\n");
}



void midd( int choice, double *indata, double *outdata, int n, int row, int col, int bands)
{
    Image *inputImage;
    byte        **image;    
    unsigned int        r,  c;      
    int i;
    unsigned int    no_of_rows, 
            no_of_cols, 
            no_of_bands;    
    COLOR_FORMAT color_space;
    int check=0;
     no_of_bands = bands;

    no_of_rows =  row;

    no_of_cols =  col;

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    { if (check<indata[i])
          check=indata[i];
    }


    if (check<=1){

      for (i=0;i<n;i++){
      //outdata[i]=  floor(255*indata[i]);    //By Krishna Regmi
      indata[i]=  floor(255*indata[i]);
   }}
    else
    {for (i=0;i<n;i++)
      //outdata[i]=  floor(indata[i]);      //By Krishna Regmi
      indata[i]=  floor(indata[i]);
     }

    // mexPrintf("\ first value after scaling to 0-255 %f\n", outdata[0]);

    // typedef enum {PBM, PGM, PPM, EPS, TIF, GIF, RAS, ITX, IRIS, CCC, BIN, VIP, GLR, BTC, BRC, HUF, ZVL, ARITH, BTC2, BTC3, DPC, ZON, ZON2, SAFVR, JPG, WVQ, FRA, VQ, XVQ} IMAGE_FORMAT;

    //typedef enum {BINARY, GRAY_SCALE, RGB, HSL, HSV, SCT, CCT, LUV, LAB, XYZ}

    inputImage=new_Image (BMP, RGB, no_of_bands, row,  col, CVIP_BYTE, REAL ); 

    for(bands=0; bands < no_of_bands; bands++) {
    image = getData_Image(inputImage, bands);
    for(r=0; r < no_of_rows; r++) {
            for(c=0; c < no_of_cols; c++)
            {
                image[r][c]=outdata[r+row*c+row*col*bands];        /* passing data from MATLAB variable to CVIPtools variable   */
             }
         }
    }


    //Image *CVIPhalftone(Image *cvip_Image, int halftone, int maxval, float fthreshval, CVIP_BOOLEAN retain_image, CVIP_BOOLEAN verbose)

   //inputImage= CVIPhalftone(cvipImage,QT_THRESH,255,0.5,CVIP_NO,CVIP_NO);

    inputImage  =   CVIPhalftone(inputImage, choice, 255, 0.5, CVIP_NO, CVIP_NO);

 for(bands=0; bands < no_of_bands; bands++) {
        image = getData_Image(inputImage, bands);
    for(r=0; r < no_of_rows; r++) {
            for(c=0; c < no_of_cols; c++)
            {
                outdata[r+row*c+row*col*bands] = floor(image[r][c]);     /* passing data back to MATLAB variable from CVIPtools variable */

            }
         }
      }

    }       /* end of wrapper function*/


/* main gateway function*/

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *outdata, *indata;
    int    r,c,bands;
    const mwSize *dim_array;
    int choice,n;
    //char color_type;
    // COLOR_FORMAT color_space;
    //int choice;
    //int n = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]);
    n = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]);
    indata = mxGetData(prhs[0]);
    //double *indata = (double *)mxGetData(prhs[0]);
    dim_array = mxGetDimensions(prhs[0]);
    //color_type = mxGetChars(prhs[1]);

    choice = mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);
    r         = dim_array[0];
     c         = dim_array[1];
      bands         = dim_array[2];

      // mexPrintf("total elements %d\n", n);

    if(bands==3){

        plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(3, dim_array, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);

    }
    else
    { plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(r,c,mxREAL);
      bands=1;
       }
      outdata = mxGetData(plhs[0]);
    midd(choice, indata, outdata, n, r, c, bands);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a segmentation fault in your mex code. Check the input datatypes. Make sure that the data type of the parameters passed from matlab match those that are expected by the C function. Also, keep in mind that matlab arrays are column-major, and the sizes are [rows, cols], not [width height].

If you can't spot the problem easily, then you would need to attach a debugger to the matlab process, or add a lot of `mexPrintf`'s into your code to see where exactly it fails.